# CDK Cloudformation deployment creates an S3 bucket but fails because "already exists"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK template that I'm deploying using Cloudformation.

Everytime I try to deploy it, the S3 bucket in question gets created but immediately fails with the error "xxxxx already exists."

I've tried this a number of times, making sure to delete the bucket in the console before deploying, but it still fails with that message. Usually I retry after immediately deleting the bucket and the stack, but one time I waited 3-4 hours and still got the same error.

Any advice here?

Comment: Please share the template.

Comment: Just use different name for the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Bucket names are global. It could be that another AWS customer created a bucket with the same name. In your case, it could be that your stack is trying to create the same bucket twice. Check your code and the synthesized template and you'll probably find the same bucket twice.

By the way, it's not recommended to name the resources yourself in CDK. Let it infer the name automatically from the logical IDs.